# Please stuck for two days on this custom class detail class view is not display record

Tags: django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCf4g.png)Please can anyone help me out on this issue
Please stuck for two days on this custom class detail class view is not display record, i
think is reverting back to the logged in user data instead of the detail from the list
my code below not error even printed out the variable but still blank

view.py

```
class ListOfEnrolledCandidate(View):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        users = 
 CustomUser.objects.filter(user_type=6).select_related('candidates')
        context = {
        'users': users
        }
        return render(request, 'superadmin/candidates/list- 
        enrolled.html', context)

class CandidateProfile(View):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=int(kwargs['id']))
        print(user)
        return render(request, 'superadmin/candidates/profile- 
        detail.html',{'users':user.id})
```

models.py

```
class Candidates(models.Model):
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, 
     on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
     related_name="candidates")
     profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', 
     upload_to='upload')
     middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     gender = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
     null=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    local = models.ForeignKey(Local, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    candclass = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    parentno = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True)
    exam_year = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', 
    upload_to='media/uploads')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.middle_name


class CandidateSubject(models.Model):    
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, null=True, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    subject2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    subject3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    subject4 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    subject5 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    subject6 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    subject7 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    subject8 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    subject9 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    subject10 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.subject1, self.subject2}'
```

this is a one to one relationship with user

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data = ((1, "HOD"), (2, "Staffs"), (3, "Teachers"), (4, 
"Parents"), (5, 
    "Students"), (6, "Candidates"))
    user_type = models.CharField(default=1, choices=user_type_data, 
max_length=15)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.first_name

i enjoy custom class more than functions please anyone help me out 
with this code

list-detail.html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4>List of Candidate Registered</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-striped table-hover" 
                  id="tableExport" style="width:100%;">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name </th>
                    <th>Middle Name </th>
                    <th>Date Enrolled</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th colspan="4">Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for c in candidates %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{ c.admin.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ c.admin.first_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ c.admin.last_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ c.middle_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ c.created_at }}</td>
                    <td>{{ c.candclass }}</td>
                    <td>{{ c.exam_year }}</td>
                    <td>
  <a href="{% url 'emisapp:update-page'c.admin.id %}" class="btn btn- 
   primary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> 
       </a></td>
 <td><a href="{% url 'emisapp:profile-page' 
c.admin.id %}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-user-check">
```

{% endfor %}

```
profile-page.html
<div class="tab-content tab-bordered" id="myTab3Content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="about" 
                  role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab2">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-6 b-r">
                    <strong>Full Name</strong>
                    <br>
                    <p class="text-muted">{{ c.admin.first_name }} 
                   </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-6 b-r">
                    <strong>Mobile</strong>
                    <br>
                    <p class="text-muted">{{ c.parentno }}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-6 b-r">
                    <strong>Email</strong>
                    <br>
                    <p class="text-muted">{{ c.admin.email }}</p>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the `list-enrolled.html` template and the `profile-detail.html` template? Does the List of Enrolled Candidates display correctly?

Comment: thank you evergreeen for your response, the list-enrolled.html is well displayed but the profile-detail.html is blank have spent several days figuring this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `CandidateProfile` class it may be better to use a [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview):

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class CandidateProfile(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'candidate'
    template_name = 'superadmin/candidates/profile-detail.html'
    
    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=int(self.kwargs['id']))
```

As we have set `context_object_name` to `candidate` this means that django will pass the CustomUser object to the template, and we can access this object using `candidate`.

profile-page.html will look something like this:

```
         <div class="tab-content tab-bordered" id="myTab3Content">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="about" 
              role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab2">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-6 b-r">
                <strong>Full Name</strong>
                <br>
                <p class="text-muted">{{ candidate.first_name }} 
               </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-6 b-r">
                <strong>Mobile</strong>
                <br>
                <p class="text-muted">{{ candidate.admin.parentno }}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-6 b-r">
                <strong>Email</strong>
                <br>
                <p class="text-muted">{{ candidate.email }}</p>
              </div>
```

Comment: Wow, this works greatly, thanks for saving my ass, sorry how can you explain the logic in a nutshell

Comment: This site might help you to understand how DetailView works

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

Comment: thanks, i will check out